# Meteor insert method callback should execute async

Tags: javascript, meteor, frontend

Hello Stackoverflow community,

**In nuts**

I am wondering why the insert callback is not being called async properly as the documentation says, having a code like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  addUpdate: function (text) {
    Updates.insert({
      text: text,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      owner_email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address,
      owner_username: Meteor.user().username
    }, function(e, id) {
      debugger; //<-- executed first with 'e' always undefined
    });
    debugger; //<-- executed after
  }
});
```

the `debugger` inside the callback function is executed before the `debugger` afterwards, if the function is async the debugger inside the callback should be called at the end right?

**More info**

I am very new with meteor, the thing is that I am trying to make an small app, and experimenting, by now I wanted to confirm what I had understood about some concepts in this case the "insert" method. given the following code:

```
lib/collections/updateCollection.js

Update = function (params, id) {
  params = params || {};
  // define properties for update model such as text
  this._text = params.text;
}

Update.prototype = {
  // define some getters and setters, such as doc
  get doc() {
    return {
      createdAt: this.createdAt,
      text: this.text,
      owner_email: this.owner_email,
      owner_username: this.owner_username
    };
  },
  notify: function notify(error, id) {
    var client, notification, status;

    client = Meteor.isClient ? window.Website : false;
    notification = (client && window.Hub.update.addUpdate) || {}
    status = (!error && notification.success) || notification.error;

    if (client) {
      return client.notify(status);
    }
  }
  save: function save(callback) {
    var that;

    that = this;
    callback = callback || this.notify;

    Updates.insert(that.doc, function (error, _id) {
      that._id = _id;
      callback(error, _id); <-- here is the deal
    });
  }
}

lib/methods/updateService.js

updateService = {
  add: function add(text) {
    var update;

    update = new Update({
      text: text,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      owner_email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address,
      owner_username: Meteor.user().username
    });

    update.save();
  },

  // methods to interact with the Update object
};

lib/methods/main/methods.js

Meteor.methods({
  addUpdate: function (text) {
    updateService.add(text);
  }
});
```

My expectations here is when the client do something like `Meteor.call('addUpdate', text);` and everything is cool, a successful message is shown, otherwise the error is "truth" and an error message is shown. What is actually happening is that the callback is always called with error undefined (like if everything es cool), the callback also is not being called async, it is just called directly.

Even when I turn off the connection the update insertion shows a success message.

Any idea? maybe my app structure is making meteor work wrong? I really do not know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the `that.doc` property being populated?

Comment: Inside the Update.property, I just skip it in order to make the code smaller, is a getter. I am going to update the code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is executing inside a method. On the client, methods are executed simply to simulate what the server will do before the server responds (so that the app seems more responsive). Because the DB changes here are just simulating what the server is already doing, they are not sent to the server, and therefore synchronous. On the server, all code runs inside a [Fiber](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers), so it acts synchronous. (However, Fibers run in parallel just like normal callback-soup Node.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gaelan, ok I think I got you, but what if I want to preserve that feature and make the server respond with error if the record could not be inserted? in order to do something like: user make the update and it is showed but if the server couldn't insert it delete it.

Comment: @AlexisDuran If you call the method using `Meteor.apply`, you can pass a callback as the last argument. This callback will be called after the server returns. However, the client-side simulation will still run. If you, for some reason, don't want a client-side simulation at all, just don't run the `Meteor.methods` call on the client (put it in `server/` or a `if (Meteor.isServer)` block).